# Why we use escape => false in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel',    
    array(
        'action'=>'index', 
        'page:'.$this->request->data['Transaction']['page']
    ),
    array(
        'class'=>'btn btn-default', 
        'escape'=>false
    ), 
    'Do you want to cancel ?'
);
```

Comment: what is the problem exactly? explian!

Comment: If you want to display some markup in the input field then you have to use that.

Comment: @sarvesht Please add little description so reader can identify vote actually expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your label is HTML rather than plain text.

You don't want to insert a literal `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>` text, you want an HTML tag to display an icon.

```
    // lib/Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php
    if (isset($options['escapeTitle'])) {
        $escapeTitle = $options['escapeTitle'];
        unset($options['escapeTitle']);
    } elseif (isset($options['escape'])) {
        $escapeTitle = $options['escape'];
    }

    if ($escapeTitle === true) {
        $title = h($title);
    } elseif (is_string($escapeTitle)) {
        $title = htmlentities($title, ENT_QUOTES, $escapeTitle);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML special characters in `$title` will be converted to HTML entities. To disable this conversion, we set the escape option to false in the `$options` array:

```
$this->Html->link($title, $url, $options);
```

Read: [Manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html)

Answer (score 0):

All HTML characters will be escaped on Views by default, just as if you used `htmlentities()` on it, so for this reason, all elements created by CakePHP Helpers (`$this->Html->link()` in this case) need the param `'escape' => false` to avoid that conversion, be it trying to use nested tags or nested HTML in the label or so.

[Reference](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link)